# Compressing multiple line breaks \n and tabs \t from a string in R

Tags: r, regex, tabs, compression, line-breaks

I tried to use

```r
gsub('(\t\\n)+','\n',.)
```

function to compress multiple `\n` and `\t` into only `\n`, but it didn't work.

I'm kinda confused by regex, so can anyone help me? Please find the R console screenshot below:

[image: R console]

Comment: @G5W, it would not work; as [\\n] matches "\\" and 'n' separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("\t*\n[\t\n]*", "\n", x)
```

This will replace all sequences of tabs and newlines where one newline char is obligatory with a single newline (LF) char.

See an [R demo online](https://ideone.com/4q6XY3):

```r
x <- "A\tB\t\n\n\n\nD\tF"
gsub("\t*\n[\t\n]*", "\n", x)
## => [1] "A\tB\nD\tF"
```

*Details*:

- `\t*` - zero or more tabs
- `\n` - an LF, newline char
- `[\t\n]*` - zero or more TAB or LF chars.

If you need to incluse CR as an optional char, use

```r
gsub("[\t\r]*\n[\t\r\n]*", "\n", x)
```

Comment: I have another question. It doesn't work when there are spaces among them. In that case, what would be the code? Plus, after using strsplit(), how can I extract the last string? Thank you very much.

Comment: @YahuiPeng You can simply rely on `\s` construct, `gsub("\\s*\n\\s*", "\n", x)`

Answer (score 1):

If your questions is to convert consecutive "\n"s and "\t"s (might mixed together) into **"\n"**, then the following would work.

```
gsub("(\\t|\\n)+","\\n",inputStr)
```

If '\t' (real TAB character) should included, then

```
gsub("(\t|\\t|\\n)+","\\n",inputStr)
```